# Find real $a$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\ln(e^x+a) - x\right)\left(e^x+x\right) =1$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\ln(e^x+a) - x\right)\left(e^x+x\right) =1.$$

I tried to use some fundamental limits, but I didn't get far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\ln(e^x+a)=\ln e^x+\ln (1+a/e^x)-x=\ln(1+a/e^x)$$

therefore

$$(\ln(e^x+a) - x)(e^x+x) =\ln(1+a/e^x)(e^x+x)=\frac{\ln(1+a/e^x)}{a/e^x}\frac{a(e^x+x)}{e^x}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Basic starting point for me was to understand what
is the form of limit.
i found it to be infinity into 0 form, then manipulate it
to get the answer.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know to use MathJax.

Comment: Can the downvoters please give some kind of explanation?

Comment: @DavidLui See my comment. This was really my reason for downvoting - plus I can barely read this.